# html span not working

Tags: html, css

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

However, I didn't manage to do this using `span` and I don't how to do this with any other html tag.. Here's my current html:

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <table style="margin-top: 15px;" width="550px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;">
            <p style="padding: 23px; font-size: 16px; color: black; font-weight: bold;">Sold by: The Vendor <span>address</span></p>
          </td>
          <td style="text-align: right;">
            <p style="padding: 23px; font-size: 16px; color: black; font-weight: bold;">Invoiced to: The Customer <span>address</span></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: And what is it doing instead?

Comment: i tried to do this that way but the address is coming in new paragraph and not under the address text
<p><b>sold by:</b>the vendor<br>address<br><p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems you need 4 columns, not 2. Second, use `vertical-align: top;` to be sure they are not in the middle and the first lines in the neighbour cells are aligned correctly; and remove vertical padding or set it to each column; and also substitute `p` tags with `span`s or make sure paddings are consistent. Finally, you need `<br>` to add newlines.

Here's an approximate example (though, I haven't wrapped 2 new cells' contents with `span`s that set distinct font-size and font color, you can add those by youself):

```html
<table style="margin-top: 15px;" width="550px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top; padding-right: 5px;">
        <span style="font-size: 16px; color: black; font-weight: bold;">Sold by:</span>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
        The Vendor<br>address<br>...
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top; padding-right: 5px;">
        <span style="font-size: 16px; color: black; font-weight: bold;">Invoiced to:</span>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
        The Customer<br>address<br>...
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

PS you may implement this with 2 columns using `inline-block` elements (note that `vertical-align` is applied to both cell and inner span, second one to prevent the inner elements to be aligned to top *by baseline of text*; or you may try `vertical-align: text-top` [for the `div`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#Result) instead of `top` for the `span`):

```html
<table style="margin-top: 15px;" width="550px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; font-size: 16px; color: black;">
        <span style="vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;">Sold by:</span>
        <div style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 5px;">The Vendor<br>address<br>...</div>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; font-size: 16px; color: black;">
        <span style="vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;">Invoiced to:</span>
        <div style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 5px;">The Customer<br>address<br>...</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, this may be more difficult to align horizontaly especially you can have issues with screens of little width.

Comment: Yes @Yakovl the better implementation you shared. thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

Is this for an Email or Webpage?

Either way, you'll want to break each column into it's own TD. Give each TD a width, all TD's width within the Table should add up to your table width (550px).

You could try something like this, just adjust spacing as needed

```html
<td style="text-align: left;" width="112">
  <p style="width:50%; padding: 0 23px 23px; font-size: 16px; color: black; font-weight: bold;">Sold by:</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: right;" width="112">
  <p style="width:50%; padding: 23px; font-size: 16px; color: black; font-weight: bold; text-align:left;">The Vendor address</p>
</td>
```

Comment: this is not working . like the sold by: the name - and its address beneath the name

Comment: It will work you if replace your first <td> with my code. In the code snippet it wont work because it's missing the <table><tr> { my code here ) </tr></table> wrapper.